# How to copy set of files and folder structure with identical names but different file extensions

Tags: command-line, copy

Let me preface this by saying that I am a linux novice to be sure. I am looking for a way to copy files of with the same name but a different file extension.

Some background:

I have a large collection of music. The vast majority is in .flac format. In order to play my collection in my car I transcoded all of it into different file formats. I have a library of source .flac files and then identical matching .mp3 and .m4a (AAC) transcoded libraries, due to various file formats supported by the cars we own. I have a flash drive in my car that supports AAC and MP3 playback, but not flac. On the flash drive is music that I have selected from the larger library on my computer. I have no want for lots of complete albums and thus I only have files on my flashdrive that I hand picked from the larger library.

Now, we sold our old car and bought a new one, and this one supports FLAC playback. Rather than manually matching the flac tracks on the new flash drive with the mp3 tracks on the old one, I was wondering if it would be possible via terminal to match the contents from Flashdrive1 with COMPUTER1 master library, and then copy the corresponding matched filenames with the desired filetype and appropriate folder structure to FLASHDRIVE2

tl:dr

take contents from:

```
FLASHDRIVE1
    \Artist
        \Album
            \01 tracktitle.mp3
             02 tracktitle.mp3
```

find corresponding .flac version with identical file structure and naming scheme, only different file format within:

```
COMPUTER1
    \Artist
        \Album
            \01 tracktitle.flac
             | 02 tracktitle.flac
             | 03 tracktitle.flac
```

copy to:

```
FLASHDRIVE2
    \Artist
        \Album
            \01 tracktitle.flac
              | 02 tracktitle.flac
```

*In this hypothetical, Track 03 being omitted because it does not exist on the Flashdrive1 and therefore do not want it on Flashdrive2

I know that I have to invoke find and set the filetype and that grep would be involved, but I am having trouble coming up with the proper syntax. I have googled for any similar questions but haven't been able to find any that achieve what I am looking to do. If I haven't looked hard enough, feel free to flame me. However help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to edit out the Elementary OS part because a: eOS is off-topic here, and b: the command line should work the same.

Comment: Can't you just do `cp /Artist/Album/*.mp3 FLASHDRIVE1` & `cp /Artist/Album/*.flac FLASHDRIVE2`? Or am I missing what you wanted to do?

Comment: **UPDATE** For my last comment, I would recommend just using [muru](http://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru)'s answer as it works much better for this specific question, and mentions explanations for each part of the command.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `grep`, you might use `sed`:

```
find /path/to/flashdrive -iname '*.mp3' -printf '%P\0' |
 sed -z 's/\.mp3$/.flac/' | 
 rsync -aP --files-from=- -0 /path/to/computer1 /path/to/flashdrive  --dry-run
```

In order:

- `find` to find the MP3 files and print their relative paths, separated by the ASCII NUL character (`\0`)
- `sed` to replace `.mp3` and the end with `.flac`, using `-z` to process NUL-delimited limes.
- `rsync` to copy the files while retaining directory structure and permissions (`-a`), reading in file paths to copy from stdin (`--files-from=-`), using NUL-delimited lines (`-0`).

The `--dry-run` is used to simulate the copying, observe the output and run again without the option if it looks OK.

Comment: Nice answer! Good job adding explanations for each part of the command! +1